# SqlMembership on both Azure and Standalone SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sqlmembershipprovider

I'm working on an ASP.NET Web Forms application with `SqlMembershipProvider`. As it is running on Azure too, I use [KB2006191 Updated ASP.NET scripts for use with SQL Azure](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2006191/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3539) for tables and SPs.

Apparently, they do not work smoothly with a standalone SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1. Especially `dbo.aspnet_Users_DeleteUser` fires an internal error:

> Msg 8624, Level 16, State 1, Procedure aspnet_Users_DeleteUser, Line 111
>   Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor could not produce a query plan. For more information, contact Customer Support Services.

**Edit:**

I broke down the issue to one SQL statement which actually fails (even if I hard-code a value for `@UserId`):

```
DELETE FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

**Original:**

I tried fixing my SQL Server installation by [downloading a Cumulative Update Package and setting trace flag 4199](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974006). However, this did not help. To be honest, I'm not too sure whether I applied the patch properly. I'm doing further research on this.

Moreover, I tried to rewrite the SP a little, as I found some tips on the web. This did not help either, and the same query is generated by `aspnet_regsql` for standalone SQL Server anyway. Actually, I tried to get rid of a subquery around line 111 by turning this:

```
IF ((@TablesToDeleteFrom & 1) <> 0 AND
    (@TablesToDeleteFrom & 2) <> 0 AND
    (@TablesToDeleteFrom & 4) <> 0 AND
    (@TablesToDeleteFrom & 8) <> 0 AND
    (EXISTS (SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE @UserId = UserId)))
```

... into this:

```
IF ((@TablesToDeleteFrom & 15) <> 0)
```

Did anybody come across similar issues dealing with membership and both Azure and standalone SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) and [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/04/10046103.aspx), the [ASP.NET Universal Providers For SqlExpress 1.1](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers) package (System.Web.Providers) is the officially supported method of enabling the SQL membership, role and session providers across SQL Azure and standalone SQL Server.

Comment: We use the universal providers and they work great.  Note that they only work for ASP.Net 4.0+.

Comment: +1 (and answer) for a real improvement. I got my actual problem fixed now by indexing a column in one of my own tables which had a foreign-key reference to `aspnet_Users`. This isn't commonly adaptive, however.